# making my site show mysite.com/login/ instead of mysite/login.php?action=login&var=1234

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I know this can be done using mod_rewrite but I am not sure since I am using Xampp and someone said it won't work on a windows machine. So I guess I can't even test it for now.

so if I have login.php, index.php etc...
I would like them to appear as `mysite.com/login/` or `mysite.com/index/` accordingly.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# specific rule to handle these URLs
RewriteRule ^login/?$ /login.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^index/?$ /index.php [L,NC]

# OR a generic once to forward all /foo to /foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you @anubhava , this seems to actually work on my XAMPP. If I get this staright, the first set of rules is to limit to only known files, and the other set of rulez would is generic for all requests right?

Comment: @Ted: Yes that is right. If you want to target only known files then comment out generic rule and comment known file rules if you want to catch all.